# Global vector causing a segfault at end of c++ program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, global-variables

This program prints out "bye" at the very end and then segfaults. I have no idea why. I think it might have something to do with the global vector? I've played around with it and discovered that if I take away the cout << i,j and the cout << endl, it will segfault without printing anything. n,p,k, and T aren't very big, at most 30.

```
    int n, p, k;
    vector<vector<int>> plates;

    int main() {
      int T;
      cin >> T;
      for (int t = 1; t != 1 + T; ++t) {
        cin >> n >> k >> p;
        plates.resize(n + 1, vector<int>(k + 1, 0));
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
          for (int j = 1; j <= k; ++j) {
            cin >> plates[i][j];
            cout << i << "," << j << "\t";
          }
          cout << endl;
        }
      }
      cout << "bye" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a global `vector` in the first place?

Comment: You are probably going out of bounds of your vector.

Comment: *n,p,k, and T aren't very big, at most 30.* -- Then you should place these values directly into the variables, and not use `cin`.  We have no idea what is really being inputted with your code.  All we have is your promise, and promises are many times not kept when it comes to getting input from somewhere.

Comment: l use a global so l don't have to pass in params. This is for a coding competition in which time = more points. @drescherjm

Comment: Use reference parameters instead. Global variables should be kept to a minimum. When your code is hundreds of thousands of c++ source lines and you need to debug you will thank yourself for not doing using globals.

Answer (score 1):

```
plates.resize(n + 1, vector<int>(k + 1, 0));
```

`resize()` does not do what you think it does. `resize()` does ***not*** set every value in the resized vector to the 2nd parameter, here. Only ***new*** values in the vector, if it grows, are set to this value.

So, if on the first time through the outer loop the vector was 2 rows by 2 columns, and the second time through the outer loop the dimensions are specified as 50x50, this will add 48 more values to `plates`, which each value being a vector with 50 values.

But the first two values in `plates` vector remain unchanged, with their original two-valued vector in them.

The solution seems to be obvious: add `plates.clear()` before this `resize()`.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it.